# Days between status change in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need find the number of days between status change in SQL Server 2014.

For example, please see the data below

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| status | Number | updated_on | opened_at   |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Draft  | 100    | 2017-11-03 | 2017-11-03  |
| Draft  | 100    | 2017-12-12 | 2017-11-03  |
| WIP    | 100    | 2017-12-12 | 2017-11-03  |
| Appr   | 100    | 2018-01-05 | 2017-11-03  |
| Launch | 100    | 2018-01-10 | 2017-11-03  |
| Close  | 100    | 2018-01-11 | 2017-11-03  |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

Based on the above input, I need to get

```
Draft --- 40 days,
WIP --- 23 days,
appro -- 5 days,
deploy/launch - 1 days,
closed --- 69 days
```

Please help me with SQL query to arrive this results.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your logic. It's not clear.

Comment: Hi, For a ticket, there will be multiple status say Draft, wip, approved etc..I need to find the number of days between 2 status....in my example...you can see it was in draft status on 2017-11-03 again on draft on 2017-12-12 and changed to WIP on 2017-12-13 (In my example it was wrong (2017-12-12)...so it stays on draft for 40 days..Like that, it was changed to appr on 2018-01-05, so it stay on wip for 23 days... like that for each status I need to find how many days a ticket stay in a particular status...Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your numbers are right.  But this should do what you want, assuming that the statuses are unique:

```
select status,
       datediff(day, updated_on, lead(updated_on) over (order by updated_on) ) as days
from t;
```

I don't understand the first and last numbers, though.

Comment: Yes,you are right....let me explain it clearly..The first number should be  days between Opened_at (2017-10-03) and updated_on (2017-11-03) and last number should be days between updated_on (2018-01-11) and current data (2018-02-14) . Please look at the below sample data and let me know the query...
| status | Number | updated_on | opened_at   |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Draft  | 100    | 2017-11-03 | 2017-10-03  |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Close  | 100    | 2018-01-11 | 2017-11-03  |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
tb.status,
DATEDIFF(dayofyear, tb.opened_at, tb.LastUpdate) AS  DaysInDifference
FROM
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT
status,
Max(updated_on) OVER(PARTITION BY [status]  )LastUpdate,
opened_at
FROM Table1
)AS tb
```

Comment: Yes,you are right....let me explain it clearly..The first number should be  days between Opened_at (2017-10-03) and updated_on (2017-11-03) and last number should be days between updated_on (2018-01-11) and current data (2018-02-14) . Please look at the below sample data and let me know the query...
| status | Number | updated_on | opened_at   |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Draft  | 100    | 2017-11-03 | 2017-10-03  |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
| Close  | 100    | 2018-01-11 | 2017-11-03  |

Comment: Is "and last number should be days  between updated_on (2018-01-11)   and current data (2018-02-14) "  related to  which "status " on you results?

Comment: You are expecting   days between updated_on (2018-01-11) and current data (2018-02-14)  to be "closed --- 69 days" ?